# GFCI outlets fail repeatedly in new home

Tags: wiring, gfci

I purchased new home which has never been lived in and I have had to replace three different ground fault outlets. They just quit working. Now I have one in bathroom, which had been previously replaced, that quit working again. The only thing that was plugged into outlet was a night light. Yes a night light caused the previous to quit working. Is it possible that the ground faults are cheap outlets? Menards salesman stated he never heard of brand installed in house. When I replace them, they seem to work fine for few weeks before malfunctioning again.

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Stack Exchange. There doesn't seem to be a question in your question; you may want to edit it to make it clearer what information you seek.

Comment: Have you consulted with an electrician? Do any of your neighbors complain of similar issues?

Answer (score 2):

Don't throw anything out & put in a Warranty Claim ASAP! Yes, the "Builders Grade" outlets are the lowest of the low, but you should get 10-years out of them. I'd get your wiring, service panel & circuit breakers all checked out, especially & specifically since the new outlets are failing too. That's not good at all.

Answer (score -1):

You should test your neutral and ground. The ground is supposed to be the middle pin. If they are wired incorrectly (swapped) the GFCI will detect the fact that electricity is going out the live wire and not returning to the neutral, and cut off power. Also, try insulating your live wire better, it might be leaking current to ground through the wall.

Answer (score -2):

Wow, this is quite strange. It is actually quite common for the GFCI circuit in GFCI outlets to fail but they normally fail in such a way that the outlet continues to deliver power. In fact in areas such as southwest Florida, GFCIs have a 51% fail rate. These failures are caused by [transient voltage](https://www.google.com/search?q=transient%20voltage&oq=transient%20voltage&aqs=chrome..69i57&sourceid=chrome&es_sm=91&ie=UTF-8#q=transients%20in%20voltage)  rather than what was plugged in to them. It could be that the failing GFCI have more to do with the power quality rather than the night light. I would start by trying a different brand (hopefully reputable one).

I’m adding this update four years after posting the original answer. I would endorse the answer by Iggy, the manufacturer should replace them, and if more people would insist on this then the manufacturer would improve their designs. I still stand by what I said above. The statistic was from a technical paper, not my own experience, I live in Utah, but I teach for a solar technical trade school (Solar Energy International) and the fact that voltage transients can cause this is common knowledge amongst the instructors and the engineers. I suspect it’s because of poorly designed electronics in the GFCI or if the manufacturer is trying to cut manufacturing costs, which is why we all insist on warranty replacements when we see anything like this.

-Kienan Maxfield

-Instructor and curriculum developer for SEI

Comment: Almost all the GFCI outlets & breakers I have replaced will not reset and do not provide power.  I agree with transient voltage spikes as a possible cause.

Comment: Wow, I would get a gadget to test your power quality.  That is terrible.  Your big loads (A/C, stove, dryer) probably don't care about line noise, and your little loads could be moved to a sub-panel that is protected based on the results of the test.  However could the problem be coming from one of your own devices?  That's something to check for.

Comment: @WolfHarper I wasn't saying this from experience. This fail rate number was from some study that I read. I'm not quite sure where to find the study but if you think I need to cite the study, I can find it again.

Comment: Why would transient voltage cause a GFCI to trip? Only transient current should cause that.

Comment: @BlueRaja - Danny Pflughoeft I don’t have a technical answer why, but I do teach for a solar technical school (SEI) and it’s common knowledge amongst the instructors that this is the case. It has come up in several technical conversations and I’ve heard it from several engineers and instructors, and it comes up from time to time in our internal instructor forums. It is a common problem with generators since the power quality is often inferior. So, yes, in a perfect world, transient voltage SHOULDN’T cause this, but in the real world, it does. Perhaps a form of RFI? (RFI is purely speculation)